# Magento editable field in admin grid with massaction

Tags: magento, grid

I did added one editable field in my custom module grid.it display textbox but when i tick the checkbox and change the textbox value i can't get it in post data.

admin grid form code

```
 $this->addColumn('banner_position', array(
   'header'    => Mage::helper('banner')->__('Position'),
   'align'    =>'left',
   'index'     => 'banner_position',
   'editable'          => true,
            'edit_only'         => true,
  ));
```

[Screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/yGG1vscUpq)

Can anyone please guide me on this